# How do I use MethodInvoker in C++?

Tags: .net, user-interface, c++-cli, backgroundworker, porting

I've got a C++/CLI application which has a background thread. Every so often I'd like it to post it's results to the main GUI. I've read [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136399/how-to-update-textbox-on-gui-from-another-thread-in-c) that MethodInvoker could work for this, but I'm struggling to convert the syntax from C# to C++:

```
    void UpdateProcessorTemperatures(array<float>^ temperatures)
    {
        MethodInvoker^ action = delegate
        {
            const int numOfTemps = temperatures->Length;
            if( numOfTemps > 0 ) { m_txtProcessor2Temperature->Text = temperatures[0]; } else { m_txtProcessor2Temperature->Text = "N/A"; }
            if( numOfTemps > 1 ) { m_txtProcessor2Temperature->Text = temperatures[1]; } else { m_txtProcessor2Temperature->Text = "N/A"; }
            if( numOfTemps > 2 ) { m_txtProcessor2Temperature->Text = temperatures[2]; } else { m_txtProcessor2Temperature->Text = "N/A"; }
            if( numOfTemps > 3 ) { m_txtProcessor2Temperature->Text = temperatures[3]; } else { m_txtProcessor2Temperature->Text = "N/A"; }
        }
        this->BeginInvoke(action);
    }
```

...gives me:

```
1>c:\projects\MyTemperatureReporter\Form1.h(217) : error C2065: 'delegate' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\projects\MyTemperatureReporter\Form1.h(217) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++/CLI doesn't support anonymous delegates, that's an exclusive C# feature.  You need to write the delegate target method in a separate method of the class.  You'll also need to declare the delegate type, MethodInvoker can't do the job.  Make it look like this:

```
    delegate void UpdateTemperaturesDelegate(array<float>^ temperatures);

    void UpdateProcessorTemperatures(array<float>^ temperatures)
    {
        UpdateTemperaturesDelegate^ action = gcnew UpdateTemperaturesDelegate(this, &Form1::Worker);
        this->BeginInvoke(action, temperatures);
    }

    void Worker(array<float>^ temperatures) 
    {
        const int numOfTemps = temperatures->Length;
        // etc..
    }
```

Comment: He isn't calling the delegate's `BeginInvoke` method, but the form's `BeginInvoke` method.  Which is exactly the right thing to do.

Comment: Also, the reason anonymous delegates haven't been supported is that the syntax for lambdas is being standardized.  I would expect the first version of Visual C++ released after the C++0x standard is accepted to add support for anonymous delegates, using the C++0x syntax for lambdas and closures.