# perform Action<> in main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface

I'm writing an app, that performs very long requests at background. After each request I need to send result to main form.

So, here is a code:

Form1.cs

```
private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Logic.GenerateStackAsync(stackSettings, delegate(FullOrder transaction)
          {
              lastOrderId.Text = transaction.OrderId;
          }
    );

    MessageBox.Show("Completed!");
}
```

Logic.cs:

```
    public static bool GenerateStack(StackSettings stackSettings, Action<FullOrder> onOrderCreated = null)
    {
         for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
         {
              // long, long request, replaced with:
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
              if (onOrderCreated != null)
              {
                  onOrderCreated.Invoke(order);
                  // tried to change it with onOrderCreated(order), no results.
              }
          }

          return true;
    }

    public static Task<bool> GenerateStackAsync(StackSettings stackSettings, Action<FullOrder> onOrderCreated)
    {
        return TaskEx.Run(() => GenerateStack(stackSettings, onOrderCreated));
    }
```

It throws an exception: "Control 'lastOrderId' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.", which can be fixed by adding `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;`, but I think that this is a bad experience. How make it right? Thank you in advance.

P.S. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1136406/1873002

Comment: This sample code does exactly what you're trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21357567/1768303

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would say that you need to use `Control.Invoke` to solve that problem:

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That helps, thank you.
Replaced `lastOrderId.Text = transaction.OrderId;` with `Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { lastOrderId.Text = transaction.OrderId; });` and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

First, [do not expose (fake-)asynchronous wrappers for your synchronous methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx).

Next, if you want to report progress updates, then use the [progress update classes provided in .NET for that purpose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

```
public static bool GenerateStack(StackSettings stackSettings, IProgress<FullOrder> progress = null)
{
     for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
     {
          // long, long request, replaced with:
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
          if (progress != null)
          {
              progress.Report(order);
          }
      }

      return true;
}
```

Then, you can call it as such:

```
private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var progress = new Progress<FullOrder>(transaction =>
  {
      lastOrderId.Text = transaction.OrderId;
  });
  await Task.Run(() => Logic.GenerateStack(stackSettings, progress));

  MessageBox.Show("Completed!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

when you use async\await u actually starting new thread you do you stuff there and you want the result to show in the main thread the UIThread thats why you need to use the Control.Invoke